# WP8 Webbrowser, stop navigation without killing page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation, browser, windows-phone-8

I have an app that uses a web browser control to navigate a website.  When the user clicks on a hyperlink that will take them out of the site I want to be able to stop the navigation.  I tried.

```
void wgBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
        if (!e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains(BASEURL))
        {
            e.cancel = true;

            return;
        }
        progressPB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This does in fact stop the navigation, but it kills the page causing a navigation error message to appear in the webbrowser.

I have tried a few things including a wgBrowser.Goback() after navigation, but that is not a real "back", and causes the page to reload complete losing data the user previously entered.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks you.

Comment: How does it kill the page? is there JS being executed when the user taps on a link? is jQuery available on the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Are u tried `IsolatedStorageSettings`? Because using `IsolatedStorageSettings` store the data will be better when the page is navigate.

Example:

```
private void tbUserName_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            if (appSetting2.Contains("MainPage2"))
            {
                appSetting2["MainPage2"] = this.tbUserName.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                appSetting2.Add("MainPage2", this.tbUserName.Text);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the `InvokeScreipt` method over `WebBrowser` control to stop page navigation.

```
yourWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.execCommand('Stop');");
```